# Sort matcher results in a custom way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 and I want to sort the matcher result in a custom way. Here is the code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#example').select2({
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
      return markup;
    },
  templateResult: formatResult,
  templateSelection: formatResult,
  tags: true,
  createTag: function (params) {
    // Don't offset to create a tag if there is no @ symbol
    if (params.term.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
      // Return null to disable tag creation
      return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term +' <span class="new-category-text">Click to add as new option</span>',
        tag: true
      }
    }
    return null;
  },
  matcher: matchCustom,
  sorter: function(results) {
    for (var x in results) results[x].text.includes('Click to add as new option') ? results.push(results.splice(x, 1)[0]) : 0;
    return results;
  },
});

});

function formatResult(state)
{

  if (state.text === '-- Select --') {
    return '<span class="text-danger">'+state.text+'</span>';
  }
  if (!state.id || !state.element) {
    // console.log(state);
    return state.text;
  }

  if(state.element.dataset.global === '1'){
    return '<span>'+state.text+'</span><span class="float-right">Standard</span>';
  }else{
    return '<span>'+state.text+'</span>';
  }
}

function matchCustom(params, data) {
/*     console.log("params",params);
    console.log("data",data); */
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
    }

    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }
    // var exactMatchedData = {};
    // var modifiedData = {};
    // if(data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1){
    //     if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    //         exactMatchedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
    //     }else{
    //         modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
    //     }
    //     return $.extend(exactMatchedData, modifiedData);
    // }

    // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
    // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
    if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
        var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
        // modifiedData.text += ' (matched)';

        // You can return modified objects from here
        // This includes matching the `children` how you want in nested data sets
        return modifiedData;
    }

    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

This works normally. For matcher, I have written the custom function. Currently, it is returning the options if it find the match in any place on the options. And, I want to return all those matched options as well, but what I want exactly is to order the result, like I want to show the exact match at the first and other match next.

Let me explain  with an example:

For an example if you run the attached code snipped, and type `a` on the select box the results will show as:

[image: screenshot]

Here, you can see the order as `January`,`February`, `March`, `April`, `May`, `August` But, instead I want the exact match on the top and others match on next order. In this case, I want the results in order:
`April, August, January, Feburary, March, May`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqet1sbf/) link incase if you need it

Comment: Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Using select2.sorter callback is already correct. Unfortunately I can't find many documentation about sorter callback.

I edited your snippet: all element (matches) that starts with your search keyword will be put on top by putting it in separate array `toInsertInIndex0`. Later, that separate array will be merged back to `results` array.

```js
...
  sorter: function(results) {
    if(term == undefined) term = ''; // it is your search term (global variable)
    for (var x in results) { 
      if(results[x].text.includes('Click to add as new option')) {
        results.push(results.splice(x, 1)[0])
      }
    }
    var toInsertInIndex0 = [];
    for (var x in results) {
      if(results[x].text.toUpperCase().substr(0, term.toUpperCase().length) == term.toUpperCase()) {
        var spliced = results.splice(x, 1)[0];
        toInsertInIndex0.push(spliced);
      }
    }
    for(var x = toInsertInIndex0.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
      results.unshift(toInsertInIndex0[x]);
    }
    return results;
  },
...
```

See snippet below for demo

```js
var term = "";
$(function(){
  $('#example').select2({
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
      return markup;
    },
  templateResult: formatResult,
  templateSelection: formatResult,
  tags: true,
  createTag: function (params) {
    // Don't offset to create a tag if there is no @ symbol
    if (params.term.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
      // Return null to disable tag creation
      return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term +' <span class="new-category-text">Click to add as new option</span>',
        tag: true
      }
    }
    return null;
  },
  matcher: matchCustom,
  sorter: function(results) {
    if(term == undefined) term = '';
    for (var x in results) { 
      if(results[x].text.includes('Click to add as new option')) {
        results.push(results.splice(x, 1)[0])
      }
    }
    var toInsertInIndex0 = [];
    for (var x in results) {
      if(results[x].text.toUpperCase().substr(0, term.toUpperCase().length) == term.toUpperCase()) {
        var spliced = results.splice(x, 1)[0];
        toInsertInIndex0.push(spliced);
      }
    }
    for(var x = toInsertInIndex0.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
      results.unshift(toInsertInIndex0[x]);
    }
    return results;
  },
});

});

function formatResult(state)
{

  if (state.text === '-- Select --') {
    return '<span class="text-danger">'+state.text+'</span>';
  }
  if (!state.id || !state.element) {
    // console.log(state);
    return state.text;
  }

  if(state.element.dataset.global === '1'){
    return '<span>'+state.text+'</span><span class="float-right">Standard</span>';
  }else{
    return '<span>'+state.text+'</span>';
  }
}

function matchCustom(params, data) {
term = params.term;
/*     console.log("params",params);
    console.log("data",data); */
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
    }

    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }
    // var exactMatchedData = {};
    // var modifiedData = {};
    // if(data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1){
    //     if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    //         exactMatchedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
    //     }else{
    //         modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
    //     }
    //     return $.extend(exactMatchedData, modifiedData);
    // }

    // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
    // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
    if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
        var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
        // modifiedData.text += ' (matched)';

        // You can return modified objects from here
        // This includes matching the `children` how you want in nested data sets
        return modifiedData;
    }

    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Preview:
[image: preview1]

Comment: Perfect, is it possible by passing `term` variable as params instead of creating the global one.